# Visual Basic Capture output of cmd

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, vba, process

I want Visual Basic to be able to run the "make" command on the directory "C:\projectTest\".

I tried to use this:

```
    Dim output As String = String.Empty

    Using Process As New Process
        Process.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd")
        Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\projectTest\"
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        Process.Start()
        Process.BeginOutputReadLine()
        AddHandler Process.OutputDataReceived,
 _
           Sub(processSender As Object, lineOut As DataReceivedEventArgs)
               output += lineOut.Data + vbCrLf
           End Sub

        Using InputStream As System.IO.StreamWriter = Process.StandardInput
            InputStream.AutoFlush = False
            InputStream.WriteLine("make")
        End Using
        Do
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop Until Process.HasExited
    End Using
```

This code is able to capture the "gcc ..." part of the console (comes from the Makefile), but will not capture the error (which does pop up if I manually open cmd and run make on that directory).

How can I capture everything that appears including the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More than one problem.  First off, as @shf301 already told you, you forgot to read stderr.  He in turn forgot to add an extra line:

```
    Process.Start()
    AddHandler Process.OutputDataReceived, _
       Sub(processSender As Object, lineOut As DataReceivedEventArgs)
           output += lineOut.Data + vbCrLf
       End Sub
    Process.BeginOutputReadLine()
    AddHandler Process.ErrorDataReceived, _
       Sub(processSender As Object, lineOut As DataReceivedEventArgs)
           output += lineOut.Data + vbCrLf
       End Sub
    Process.BeginErrorReadLine()
```

There's another very cumbersome problem, your event handlers run late.  They fire *after* the process has already exited.  A side effect of these handlers running on a thread-pool thread.  You'll need to wait for an arbitrary (and unguessable) amount of time before you use the *output* variable:

```
    Do
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop Until Process.HasExited
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

This is too ugly.  Do this the way that *any* IDE or editor does it.  Redirect the output to a temporary file and read the file afterwards:

```
    Dim tempfile As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName
    Using Process As New Process
        Process.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c make 1> """ + tempfile + """ 2>&1"
        Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\projectTest"
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Process.Start()
        Process.WaitForExit()
        output = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(tempfile)
        System.IO.File.Delete(tempfile)
    End Using
```

Some annotation with the mystic command line:

- /c tells cmd.exe to execute just the single command and then exit
- 1> redirects the output to the temporary file
- 2>&1 tells cmd.exe to redirect stderr to stdout
- the triple double quotes ensures that spaces in the tempfile name don't cause trouble.

That same `2>&1` would also have fixed your original problem ;)

Comment: You are a master! This code seems to also compile the project much faster than when it was before. I'll award you the bounty after the 21 hours have passed :)

Answer (score 2):

Errors are generally written to the `StandardError` stream and you are only reading the `StandardOutput` stream.  Add an event handler for the [`ErrorDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and you should see the errors.

```
AddHandler Process.ErrorDataReceived, _
       Sub(processSender As Object, lineOut As DataReceivedEventArgs)
           output += lineOut.Data + vbCrLf
       End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that but it still has exactly the same output (which is missing the error).

Answer (score 0):

for people like me that are wondering why we cant get errorstream, in async mode.
add line

```
process.BeginErrorReadLine()
```