# Calling G++ from C# Program

Tags: c#, c++, batch-file, gcc

I've made a C++ code editor in C# and now am trying to invoke `g++` to compile the source files. So I've copied the TDM-GCC installation besides my program and wrote a small batch script to call that.

```sh
@echo off
@set PATH="%~dp0TDM-GCC-32\bin\";%PATH%
call "%~dp0TDM-GCC-32\mingwvars.bat"
cd %1
"%~dp0TDM-GCC-32\bin\g++.exe" %2 -o %3
```

And from C# code, I'm trying to call this script by using CMD like in this script of code.

```
string fileName   = Path.GetFileName(CurrentFile);
string exeName    = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentFile) + ".exe";
string workingDir = Directory.GetParent(CurrentFile) + "";
string compile    = Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\compile.cmd";

File.Delete(Path.Combine(workingDir, exeName));

StartProcess(true, "cmd", "/c", "\"" + compile + "\"", workingDir, fileName, exeName);
```

And here is the `StartProcess` method:

```
void StartProcess(bool hidden, string command, params string[] args)
{
    ProcessStartInfo pStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    pStartInfo.FileName = command;
    pStartInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", args);
    pStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    if (hidden)
    {
        pStartInfo.RedirectStandardError  = true;
        pStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    }

    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = pStartInfo;

    proc.Start();

    logBox.Clear();

    if (hidden)
    {
        while (!proc.StandardError.EndOfStream)
        {
            logBox.AppendText(GetTimestamp() + "  Error: " + proc.StandardError.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: 26-9-14**

I doubted whether the batch file is ever called, because if I call it from cmd, it simply works. So I tried to `echo` to the standard error from the batch file like this:

```
echo %PATH% 1>&2
```

And I can see that the GCC's bin folder is in the path too, but for some reason, the exe is not getting created. But sometimes, the script works, and the exe gets created.

But whenever I execute this, there will be nothing in the LOG and also, no executable is being created. I know that the TDM-GCC's bin folder must be in the PATH, but that is what the second line of the batch script needs to do. Dunno what this is and why this error.

**End of update**

Any suggestions on how can I get it working?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you see when you set hidden to false? what happens when you start the batch file from the command line?

Comment: @ths When I start from commandline, the batch file works on my pc. But when I started from the process, it sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: "sometimes"? above, you say "whenever". so what is the difference between working and not working runs?

Comment: @ths That's the progress in two days. Some times the exe is created, sometimes the compiler simply exits.

Comment: When you say the compiler simply exits, do you mean that it writes no messages both to stderr AND stdout? I see that in your code you just log StandardError - I assume you already tried checking StandardOutput as well, but  I figure it doesn't hurt to ask anyway.

Comment: @chris Yes I tried logging both, but of no use. It just prints a message saying that you are in MinGW Console, so I stopped logging the standard output.

Comment: Well, that's a mistake, you can easily deadlock the program when it sends too much output to stdout.  If you're not interested in it then you *must* set RedirectStandardOutput to *false*.  If you are then you *must* use BeginErrorReadLine + BeginOutputReadLine instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't get that. When I set `RedirectStandardOutput` to false, it echoes 'invalid handle' to stderr. Didn't understand what that meant.

Comment: Well, not every program supports that and g++ is certainly an odd-ball.  Nothing you can but redirect it.  *Do* read it, having cmd.exe take care of the redirection is [worth a try](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20789248/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant I always wonder how the IDEs that come with pre-bundled GCC get it to work. Any ideas please?

Comment: They always redirect to a file instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll try redirection and see if it works. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if anything written below really helps on this issue. But at least those hints should be useful in any case.

I suggest for the batch file

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0TDM-GCC-32\mingwvars.bat"
set "PATH=%~dp0TDM-GCC-32\bin;%PATH%"
cd /D %1
"%~dp0TDM-GCC-32\bin\g++.exe" %2 -o %3
```

**PATH** is modified after execution of `mingwvars.bat`. It could be that this batch file also modifies **PATH**. Or it runs commands like `find.exe` with the executables expected in `%SystemRoot%\System32`, but perhaps also existing in directory `bin`. I have seen already several times not working logon batch scripts because **PATH** on client computer contained as first folder path the `bin` directory of a compiler ported from Unix to Windows with executables also found in `%SystemRoot%\System32`, but working completely different as ported from Unix.

Folder paths should be added to environment variable **PATH** always without double quotes even if the folder path contains 1 or more spaces. The double quotes used in third line just make sure that a trailing space is not added additionally to **PATH** and that command `set` works even with not typical folder paths like an ampersand in path.

And folder paths should be added to environment variable **PATH** without a trailing backslash.

On command `cd` the parameter `/D` is additionally used in case of a change to a different drive must be performed, too. The command `cd` would not change the current directory if the specified path is on a different drive without parameter `/D`.

In C# code you have to make sure that `workingDir`, `fileName` and `exeName` are finally on execution of `cmd.exe` enclosed in double quotes in the arguments string as [Erti-Chris Eelmaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1936622/erti-chris-eelmaa) already wrote.

And it would be perhaps better to read in your C# application the value of environment variable **ComSpec** and use this value instead of just `cmd` for executing the batch file.

Comment: This is working on my PC!! I would wait for my testers to test too before accepting the answer. Thanks Mofi!

Comment: This is working for testers too. I'll award the bounty in 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This might, or might not be part of the problem, but you don't take care of spaces.

```
pStartInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", args);
```

you probably would want something like this:

```
pStartInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", args.Select(x => "\"" + x + "\""));
```

Comment: I'm sure that this is not the error, because I can get errors I echo to from the batch be seen in my log box.

Comment: You're currently logging StandardError. Try adding logging to StandardOutput too, and see if you get something extra. & see if you can reproduce the "behaviour" in other computers. What happens if you use shell execute instead of CMD? Does the behaviour continue if you don't hide the window at all?

Comment: It's working on my laptop, but not on my Dev pc and also not on my friend's laptops.

Comment: There is no output to standard output by the way